# IIS 8.5 and asmx Webservice - 403 forbidden error

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, iis, http-status-code-403

I noticed a real strange behavior on my website. I have a webservice on IIS 8.5 and a jQuery frontend application which sends request via ajax.

Everything works fine, instead of one special request.

The application is something like a shopping app. The Post-request which sends the order to the database works well if i have less than 5 items in the cart. If I have 5 items or more I get the 403 forbidden error.

In the Application Pool everythings fine. Folder permissions and Website permissions with the IIS_USR is configured with full access I think, because all other requests works fine.

The POST doesn't appear in the logfiles of IIS so I don't know which substatus the 403 has. Can anybody help? I'm searching for solution for three days now.

Comment: "The POST doesn't appear in the logfiles of IIS so I don't know which substatus the 403 has." That's impossible. Any request comes at IIS would be logged somewhere. So you need to check log files of other sites, or even HTTP.sys log files. To be simple, disable SSL and use a tool like Wireshark to capture network packets on both browser and server side, then you can easily tell what happens.

Comment: I don't find any entry in the logfiles..not in the  IIS logs and not in the http syslog file. is there any other place i can search for? or does the request maybe not even pass through and that's why it does not appear in the log files? i will try it with wireshark

Comment: Your last resort would be Wireshark. Sounds like the packets never arrive on IIS.